# Yii bitwise operations in CDbCriteria

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am trying to use bitwise operations when quering the DB using a [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) but am not having any luck; I can't find anything on the bitwise operators in the [`::compare` doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#compare-detail). I am looking for something like this:

// only grab users that are not expired.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('flags','& ' . self::USER_EXPIRED . ' = 0',true);
```

however this is not working, is there a different function I need to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [addCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail) insted of compare()? I imagine something like this should work (though have not tested it):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('flags & ' . self::USER_EXPIRED . ' = 0');
```

Out of curiousity: why do you represent information like this in bits? You could use a dedicated column (expired) with enum values ('yes', 'no'), and your code would be a lot more readable and maintainable.